# How to inspect the received TLS server certificate from backend in APIM

Tags: ssl, azure-api-management

In API Management, I am doing calls to a backend of a 3rd party using HTTPS based on their custom PKI. So the server certificate was issued by their own certificate authority.

I expected that I needed to import their CA certificate into the CA cert store in APIM. However, calls to their backend seem to work without that and I'm puzzled by it.

I suspect that their backend is not sending the correct server certificate. How can I quickly check what server certificate is being received by APIM? The `context` object doesn't seem to contain such information. I cannot simply make calls to the backend using my browser because of IP whitelisting (so I can only do calls from within Azure).

I have the rights to deploy any resource to my resource group. I'm looking for the quickest dirty hack possible for debugging purposes (also for in the future).

Comment: Might the [tracing functionality of APIM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-api-inspector) give you a clue? The trace inspector might display something about the cert being sent across.

Comment: it only shows my client certificate being sent but nothing about what server certificate is received